# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm running a code to send an email in Java. I downloaded the JavaAPI jar and added it to the path. I think I added it correctly because I see it among external libraries in the Project window and I can use all the classes (without them being underlined red).

I run following part of the code:

```
final String host = "localhost"; // not sure what is supposed to be here
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
Session session = getInstance(properties);
```

When I run the code, it compiles correctly, but produces a following error at the last line of the code stub above.

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger*

I am using IntelliJ and I am not using pom.xml.

Does anybody know, where the problem could be?

Comment: Looks like that jar is not in the classpath when you run the application.

Comment: Where can I find the correct classpath? I added it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_171\lib\ext , but that didn't help.

Comment: @JanHorčička You shouldn't normally put things in `lib/ext`. It is deprecated and has been removed in Java 9.

Comment: Exactly which library (or libraries) of JavaMail are you using?

Comment: javax.mail-api-1.6.1.jar

Comment: So where should I put it?

Comment: You are  right. It's the same problem. And thanks to your link, I found a solution. I needed to use a different library, It's the javax.mail.jar that can be downloaded here: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/

Comment: If you have a problem with MimeMessage, you need to download javax.activation jar and add it as an external library as well.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation/1.1